# Android way handling of any application/activity started

Tags: android, android-activity, android-3.0-honeycomb

Wondering if there any possibility to have a BroadcastcastReceiver or something else to handle the fact that user started(requested to start) new application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such broadcast. You can track new processes, but of cause that's more resource heavy and requires polling.